# For PL/SQL, do large companies prefer ANSI SQL joins or old Oracle joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am interviewing for a PL/SQL position with a large corporation. I will have to write a multiple choice exam. I am wondering whether the exam will likely use old-style joins (joining happens in the 'WHERE' clause) or ANSI ones. My apologies if this is not the correct forum for this question.

Comment: If it is multiple choice, the questions shouldn't be ambiguous (where either is a correct answer).  If it is a "write a query to produce this data", you should follow the best practices for that database to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Show them you know both styles.**

I can tell you by experience that **PL/SQL programmers prefer the Oracle-style** joins.

I have maintained PL/SQL solution and hardly ever seen an ANSI-join.

Left and right joins and more terse because of the (+) especial Oracle keyword.

Been said that, **ANSI-joins are more universal** and make it **easier to migrate** between different RDBMS.

It's probable that your interviewer, if he/she is an Oracle lifelong programmer, is unfamiliar with the ANSI-style.

**I tend to think that if you are looking for an PL/SQL position, do things the Oracle way. That's what they would expect.**

Comment: bad advice: the (+) syntax (while great) is considered obsolete by Oracle. Stick with the standard, everyone should be familiar with it by now.